# Bash / command not found

Tags: bash, sh

I run the next in bash:

```
cd /$P/"W${GU}"
GV = $(find . -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -n | tail -1 | sed 's/.*PO\.\([0-9]*\).*/\1/')
\cp $P/"Wa ${GV}"/PO.${GV}/la_${GV}_PO.${GV}.exe $P/"$JOB_NAME"/S-${SV}_PO.$SV/G
```

It return the next:

```
/tmp/h4.sh: line 3: GV: command not found
```

What is the reason?

Comment: You can't have spaces in variable assignments. It should be `GV=$( ...`

Comment: That should be an answer, user000001

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash (or sh) does not tolerate spaces around the assignment operator `=`.

```
GV=$(find . -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -n | tail -1 | sed 's/.*PO\.\([0-9]*\).*/\1/')
```

If there is a space, it interprets the first word (`GV` in this case) as a command, which is not found.

Comment: Actually, they do tolerate spaces, but the semantic of the statement changes fundamentally.